# Tauri app api request blocked by cors with api built with django restframework

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, cors, vite, tauri

https://tauri.localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

I have added https://tauri.localhost to my cors configuration in my api but it still throws the same error.
`CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [ "http://localhost:3001", "http://localhost:3003", "tauri://localhost", "https://tauri.localhost"," ]`

Comment: The error message indicates that the client is including a header named `access-control-allow-origin` in the request, which doesn't make sense since that header is a response header.

Answer (score 3):

I hope you are using http client provided by Tauri itself. I've encountered the same problem when I tried to call APIs in my tauri app using axios/fetch then after some research I used the **http** module provided by tauri and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

To make HTTP(read api) requests in Tauri app you should use [`@tauri-apps/api/http`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tauri-apps/api) module.

EXAMPLE:

`npm install -D @tauri-apps/api`

In tauri.conf.json file make sure you have this:

```
{
  "tauri": {
    "allowlist": {
      "http": {
        "all": true, // enable all http APIs. needed.
        "request": true, // enables only HTTP request API. optional
        "scope": ["https://localhost/*", "https://something.else/*"] // optional
      }
    }
  }
}
```

More can be found in the official [docs](https://tauri.app/v1/api/js/http).

*Disclaimer: JSON standard does not allow comments.*

Next, in your sample.ts file:

```
import {Body, fetch, ResponseType} from "@tauri-apps/api/http"

function apiRequest(data: FormData) {
  let body = Body.form(data);
  let response = await fetch(API_URL, {
    method: "POST",
    body: body,
    timeout: 30, //seconds
    responseType: ResponseType.JSON,
    // headers: {key: 'val'} // if needed
  });
  
  console.log(response.data);
}
```

This way you don't have to worry about CORS at all.

Thanks, @Vinay Rawat, & official docs.

I hope this helps someone.